# How to mock an object created by SUT

Tags: unit-testing, mocking

Say my SUT is a BubbleMachine which creates itself some instances of Bubble objects to use internally. However, I want it to use my MockBubble's instead .. What do I do?

Solutions:

1. Use an intermediate class BubbleFactory which I can pass to the BubbleMachine. That way I can give it a MockBubbleFactory instead.
2. As I'm using a lang which allows it, set some string on the BubbleMachine that tells it which class to instantiate for it's Bubble objects. E.g. $bubbleMachine->setBubbleClass('path/to/MockBubble.class')
3. Just have a setBubbleObject(..) kind of function  on BubbleMachine to which I pass my MockBubble. The BubbleMachine then just recycles that object instance every time it wants to do a bubble.

Any 3 of these would work for my current problem but I suspect they may make some unit testing professionals a bit uncomfortable.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, if you really feel the need to mock an object created by the SUT, then use a mocking tool that does that for you. I would say that's the cleanest solution, as it doesn't require any additional complexity in the SUT (such as a factory, setter, etc.).